# Vue.js and Firebase - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am using Vue.js and Firebase to build a little APP - now I want to create a list of my users "real database". Which does work fine, but only when I refresh it after the login.

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
>   RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

My HTML looks like this:

```
              <div class="col-12">
                  <h2>Liste</h2>
                  <div class="user-ol">
                    <ol id="example-1">
                      <li v-for="user1 in users[0]">
                       {{ user1.name }}
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                  </div>    
                </div>
```

and my created Hook like this

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    users: [],
    email: '',
    name: '',
    authUser: null,
    role: null,
    counter: null,
    active: null
},
    created () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        this.authUser = user
        if (user) {
            db.ref('users').on('value', snapshot => this.users.push(snapshot.val()));

            this.displayname = user.displayName
            this.email = user.email
            db.ref('users').child(user.uid).once('value', snapshot =>{
                if (snapshot.val()){
                    this.role = snapshot.val().role
                    this.counter = snapshot.val().counter
                    this.active = snapshot.val().active
                    this.name = snapshot.val().name
                    Vue.set(this.authUser, 'counter', this.counter)
                    Vue.set(this.authUser, 'active', this.active)
                    Vue.set(this.authUser, 'name', this.name)

                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I also had this in my list element before, but then it wouldnt even render my page and crashed with 5 of theses errors every 2 seconds

```
v-bind:class="{ 'green font-weight-bold' : user.active }"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong :/

Comment: `db.ref('users').on('value', ...` <- I'd say it's this line. See the documentation for [`.on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) ~ _"Your callback will be triggered for the initial data **and again whenever the data changes**"_

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't say for sure what you're doing wrong without trying your code, so I'll just give some view from side about it.

```
<li v-for="user1 in users[0]">
  {{ user1.name }}
</li>
```

Here you're iterating over props of single object. E.g. if user is object like `{prop1: 'str', prop2: 'str2'}` you code inside v-for acts like this `prop1.name`, `prop2.name`. Don't think it's desired.

Also `users[0]` is undefined at first.

Not sure that things I mentioned could lead to `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Anyway I suggest to start from that weird users iteration, and then to check your events from firebase (especially `.on('value', ...)` callback). You always can add some debug printings to figure out what's going on.

Comment: How do I get the data before the vue Object is build. Do I simply assign a previsioly defined array and pass it to the vue Object?

So my users[0] contains 4 users each with name, role, email etc. - why is the iteration weird?